# Integer solutions of the cubic equation $x^3-a^2bx-1-2ab=0$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics

Given the equation $x^3-a^2bx-1-2ab=0$. Is there a way to know if any integer solutions exist for $a,b$ integers greater than 1.

I've plotted graphs and tried to brute force it but found no solutions.

Update: If you set a = 1 we get a pretty simple equation: $x^3-bx-1-2b$. It seems like there would be a clear way to show that no integer solution exists for $b > 2$. Is there any restraints that would make it easier, for example letting $b,x$ be prime?

Comment: According to the rational root theorem, the only possible integer roots are factors of $-1-2ab$.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force search reveals that $a=7,b=6$ give
$$
0=x^3-a^2bx-1-2ab=x^3-294x-85=(x+17)(x^2-17x-5).
$$
Since you only specified $a,b$ to be positive integers and $x$ be any integer, $x=-17$ gives a valid solution. My search did not yield any other for $2 \leq a,b \leq 1000$ however.

Answer (score 1):

Putting
$$p=-a^2b$$
and
$$q=-1-2ab$$
into the [depressed cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic) formula, we can obtain a solution by substituting
$$
x=z-{p\over3z}
$$
which turns the depressed cubic into a quadratic in $z^3$. Then the solution of the quadratic is
$$
z^3=-{q\over2}+\sqrt R.
$$
where $R$ is the discriminant of the quadratic, the "$b^2-4ac$" part of the problem.

The formula for the discriminant, $R$, is
$$
\begin{align}
R&=\left({p\over3}\right)^3+\left({q\over2}\right)^2\\
&=-{a^6b^3\over27}+{4a^2b^2+4ab+1\over 4}
\end{align}
$$
For $a$, $b$ integers greater than one this is almost always negative, since it is negative if $a>2$ or $b>2$, so you have complex conjugate roots. If $a=b=2$ then the original equation is $x^3-8x-9=0$, which doesn't have any integer roots, since by the rational root theorem the roots must be $\pm1,3$, and these are not roots.

So you're looking for a formula involving the cube root of a square root of a negative number involving a series of squares, cubes and other powers, and hoping it will come out to be an integer.

At this point I decided to stop attempting this problem, since it looks like there is not much for it except to search for candidates using a computer, and I don't want to do that right now. However, I decided to post this partial answer since it might save someone some work. I'm sorry that I couldn't give a better answer, but I hope this at least moves things in the right direction.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how you get to the part $z^3 = -q/2 + \sqrt{R}$

Comment: I'll edit the answer to illustrate a little better.